# Get current file path in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can method detect current file name where it is called (not defined)? `__FILE__` is not working in this case.

```
# lib/foo.rb
module Foo
  def current_path
    # Somehow get path lib/bar.rb
  end
end

# lib/bar.rb
class Bar
  inculde Foo
end

# lib/test.rb
bar = Bar.new
bar.current_path # => Expected lib/bar.rb
```

Comment: The `__FILE__` and `__dir__` utilities always reference the file they're in, not the caller, nor do they take into account any other inheritance or composition factors. You need to put them in the file that you're trying to identify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the caller_locations module from ruby kernel [Returns the current execution stack---an array containing backtrace location objects.](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/2.0.0/Kernel:caller_locations)

```
module Foo
  def current_path
    caller_locations.first.label
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `caller`

```rb
# lib/foo.rb
module Foo
  def current_path
    caller[0].split(":")[0]
  end
end

# lib/bar.rb
class Bar
  include Foo
end

# lib/test.rb
bar = Bar.new
bar.current_path # => Expected lib/bar.rb
```

Comment: Updated to `caller[0].split(":")[0]`

Comment: Why not use `caller_locations` which emits [`Thread::Backtrace::Location`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Thread/Backtrace/Location.html) objects that have a `path` method? No need for an ugly `split`.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it through included callback

```
def included(base)
  base.instance_variable_set :@source_location, caller_locations.first.path
end
```

And then simply use class instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__FILE__` to get the full path of the current file:

```
> __FILE__
=> "/Users/dorianmariefr/src/template-ruby/lib/template-ruby.rb"
```